# Was there a parasha beginning at Exodus 18:21?

Tags: names, rashi, mesorah-tradition, parashas-yisro, yisro--the-man

*Rashi* to Exodus 18:1 says that *Yisro* was also called

> *Yeser* because he added (*yasar*) a *parasha* in the Torah: "And you see…" [from 18:21].

We don't have a *parasha* break before verse 21. Did *Rashi* (or whoever he's quoting) have one there, or are we not to understand him as meaning that a *parasha* begins there?

Answer (score 2):

Artscroll (in their edition of Rashi, p. 206) translates your quote as "because he caused one more **passage** of the Torah to be written" and comments

> "He caused one more passage of the Torah to be written" does not mean
>   that there was a change made in the Torah. It is a basic tenet of
>   Judaism that the Torah can never be changed. Rather, this means that
>   although Moses' method and criteria for choosing judges could have
>   been recorded without any mention of Jethro's role, the Torah,
>   nevertheless, states that Moses' action was based on Jethro's advice.

See also [Rashi to Bamidbar 10:29](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.10.29?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Numbers.10.29.1&lang2=bi) for a similar comment on Yitro.

Similar examples of passage of the Torah being credited to an individual or group are [Bamidbar 25:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.25.6?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Numbers.25.6.4&lang2=bi) (Pinchas) and [Bamidbar 27:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.27.5?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Numbers.27.5.1&lang2=bi) (daughters of Zelophehad).